# Set an image as button on Android Studio Gdx library

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libgdx

I am trying to put a button using a play image. I have followed some tutorials and cannot find the documentation to complete my project. The game is actually done, and I just need to connect the gameover screen to the game screen so I can replay the game by pushing the play image. I got stuck in this longer than I expected. I cannot change the methods because I will mess up my code. Code and images below.

```
package com.mygdx.game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Image;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.ChangeListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.viewport.FitViewport;

public class GameOverScreen extends  BaseScreen {

    private Image background;
    private Stage stage;
    private Image gameOver;
    private Image replay;

    public GameOverScreen(final MainGame game) {
        super(game);
        stage = new Stage(new FitViewport(640, 320));
        //Preparing actors
        background = new Image(game.getManager().get("bg.png", Texture.class));
        gameOver = new Image(game.getManager().get("gameover.png", Texture.class));
        replay = new Image(game.getManager().get("plybtn.png", Texture.class));

        replay.addCaptureListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
                game.setScreen(game.gameScreen);

            }
        });

        //Giving their positions and sizes
        background.setPosition(0,0);
        gameOver.setPosition(320 - gameOver.getWidth()/2, 180 - gameOver.getHeight()/2);
        replay.setPosition(320 - replay.getWidth()/2, 60 -replay.getHeight()/2);
        //Set them in stage
        stage.addActor(background);
        stage.addActor(gameOver);
        stage.addActor(replay);

    }


    @Override
    public void show() {
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        stage.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.4f, 0.5f, 0.8f, 1f);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        stage.act();
        stage.draw();
    }
}

[This is the screen that I get, it does not change the screen when I touch the button][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxVLM.png
```

Update:
This is the solution to my problem in case you need it.

```
// Declare statements at the beginning of the class 
  private Texture myTexture;
    private TextureRegion myTextureRegion;
    private TextureRegionDrawable myTexRegionDrawable;
    private ImageButton pbutton;


    // Make a texture out of the image in the MenuScreen constructor         
      myTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("plybtn.png"));
        myTextureRegion = new TextureRegion(myTexture);
        myTexRegionDrawable = new TextureRegionDrawable(myTextureRegion);
        pbutton = new ImageButton(myTexRegionDrawable);
```

Answer (score 0):

The event doesn't look like its being received. Change

`replay.addCaptureListener(new ChangeListener() {`

to

`replay.addListener(new ChangeListener() {`

or even use `ClickListener` instead. `CaptureListener` is to intercept events to disable them, not for handling and you need to return true in the capture handler to not break event handling down the tree.

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/151505/what-is-the-difference-between-a-listener-and-a-capturelistener-in-libgdx-scene2

Comment: Thank you, actually I solve it by making it a texture. I just gonna add the code below in case someone else need it in the future. I'll try your idea later though. I am now struggling trying to set an image as background. Once my character starts moving, the background just stays back like it was a picture on the wall and only the character and the stage move ahead. I believe that I have to do something in "FItViewport" but I am not sure about it.